# undefined method `permit' for "":String エラーが出ます

Tags: ruby-on-rails

## 解決したいこと

gem deviseを使用してユーザー情報登録機能を作成しています。

html.hamlの中でf.text_field :addressを記述していますが、
入力後データを保存しようとすると以下のエラーが出ます。

**エラーメッセージ**

```
NoMethodError in Users::RegistrationsController#create_address
undefined method `permit' for "[入力した内容]":String
```

---

user/registrations_controller.rb

```
def new
  @user = User.new
end

def create
  @user = User.new(sign_up_params)
  if @user.valid?
    session["devise.regist_data"] = {user: @user.attributes}
    session["devise.regist_data"][:user]["password"] = params[:user][:password]
    redirect_to addresses_path
  else
    render :new
  end
end

def create_address
  @user = User.new(session["devise.regist_data"]["user"])
  @address = Address.new(address_params)
  if @address.valid?
    @user.save
    @address = Address.new(address_params.merge(user_id: @user.id))
    @address.save
    session["devise.regist_data"]["user"].clear
    sign_in(:user, @user)
  else
    render :new_address
  end
end

protected

def address_params
  params.require(:address).permit(:post_number, :prefecture, :city, :address, :apartment)
end
```

routes.rb

```
 devise_for :users, controllers: {
    registrations: 'users/registrations',
  }

  devise_scope :user do
    get  'addresses', to: 'users/registrations#new_address'
    post 'addresses', to: 'users/registrations#create_address'
  end
```

db/migrate/addresses.rb

```
t.string     :address    , null: false
```

`rails routes`

```
        user_registration PATCH  /users(.:format)                                                                         users/registrations#update
                          PUT    /users(.:format)                                                                         users/registrations#update
                          DELETE /users(.:format)                                                                         users/registrations#destroy
                          POST   /users(.:format)                                                                         users/registrations#create
                addresses GET    /addresses(.:format)                                                                     users/registrations#new_address
                          POST   /addresses(.:format)                                                                     users/registrations#create_address
                     root GET    /                                                                                        items#index
                     user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                                                                     users#show
```

Answer (score -1):

「undefined method `permit'」（[直訳]　permitというメソッドは定義されていません）というのがエラーの内容です。

確かに、質問に含まれているプログラムには、permitというメソッドの定義が含まれていません。

問題は
・permitというメソッドを定義するのを忘れている。
・permitというメソッドを持つオブジェクトのつもりで、String型のオブジェクトを使っている。
というような、思い違いによって起きているのではないかと思われます。

paramsのように、宣言されていない変数がプログラムで使われているといった正しくないコーディングが影響している可能性もあろうかと思われます。

質問に書かれていないプログラムを使っているのであれば、それらを全て質問に追加して下さい。
プログラムの断片（不完全な一部分）だけを示されても、その修正方法を推測することは無理です。